# Database in phpmyadmin content doesn't match site content

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to replace codes in a form on my WordPress site. I have found the function within the functions.php file, which tells me the codes should be in a database called evaluation_forms_student_codes. When I go into phpmyadmin and open the DB with this name there are only 2 entries/codes listed. Neither of these are valid codes, and don't match any of the current 25 codes in use, all of which work properly. I don't see any other DB on the site where these codes could be stored.

I could manually copy and paste to replace the codes in WordPress but that seems tedious and the least favored way. I should be able to find the right DB and upload the new codes directly into it, but what I think should be the right DB must not be if the right codes aren't showing there. Just looking for some ideas.

Comment: Probably you need to track down where these 25 codes are coming from.